# How to create inline math with CellPrint within Text cell?

Tags: cells

I can create a text cell with text like this:

```
CellPrint@Cell[
    "this is a function call: f[x,y]",
    "Text"
]
```

This produces:

> this is a function call: f[x,y]

But I want `f[x,y]` to be in inline math form within the text cell, like below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create the output you want in a text cell using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>, and then use the menu command `Cell | Show Expression` to see what it looks like? When I do this, I see:

```
Cell[
    TextData[{
        "This is a function call ",
        Cell[
            BoxData[FormBox[RowBox[{"f", "[", RowBox[{"x", ",", "y"}], "]"}], TraditionalForm]],
            FormatType->"TraditionalForm"
        ],
    ":"
    }],
    "Text",
    CellChangeTimes->{{3.7781587877405243`*^9, 3.778158805740602*^9}}
]
```

and if you [`CellPrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellPrint) the above you get the desired output.

Comment: Thank you, creating a `MakeBoxes` version of the inner `Cell` does the generalization to any inline math expression inside a text cell.